# Regex stop matching if a specific string is found

Tags: php, regex, templates

I ahve the following regex:

```
/{%\h?if ((?:@)?(?:[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)(?:\.(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*))*)\h?%}([\s\S]*){%\h?end if\h?%}/U
```

It basically matches the following:

```
{% if variable %}
whatever stuff
{% end if %}
```

I am trying to modify it to match something like above OR like this:

```
{% if variable %}
some stuff
{% else %}
whatever stuff
{% end if %}
```

Afterwards I want to be able to say `if else_capture_group is not empty, then do something`.

I tried looking at negative lookaheads:

```
{%\h?if ((?:@)?(?:[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)(?:\.(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*))*)\h?%}([\s\S](?!{% else %}))(?:{%\h?else\h?%}([\s\S]*))?{%\h?end if\h?%}
```

But as per: https://regex101.com/r/wP4vS9/1, it does not work... I'm not sure why. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I tried to shorten it and added a tempered greedy token to make it work with an optional `else` block:

```
(?s){%\s*if\s+(?<var>@?(?:[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)(?:\.(?:(?1)))*)\h*%}(?<if>(?:(?!{% e(?:lse|nd if) %}).)*)(?:{%\h*else\h*%}(?<else>[\s\S]*?))?{%\h*end if\h*%}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hJ8gA2/1)

Some details:

- `{%\s*if\s+(?<var>@?(?:[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)(?:\.(?:(?1)))*)\h*%}` - the first part where we capture the `var` part (the capture group might require adjustment, but the idea is clear)
- `(?<if>(?:(?!{% e(?:lse|nd if) %}).)*)` - a tempered greedy token to match and capture the `if` code block
- `(?:{%\h*else\h*%}(?<else>[\s\S]*?))?` - an optional (due to `?` at the end) group matching the `else` part
- `{%\h*end if\h*%}` - `end` delimiter

Comment: May i bother you for your opinion on another similar one? This one simply includes an actual comparison. It is heavily based off of the answer you provided me with. https://regex101.com/r/hJ8gA2/2

Comment: I'd suggest [this one: `{%\s*if\s+(?<var>([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)(?:\.(?2))*)\s*(?<op>[<>!]?=|[<>])\s*(?<val>(?:(?1)*(?:\.(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*))*)|(?:[0-9]+))\s*%}(?<if>(?:(?!{%\h*e(?:lse|nd\h+if)\h*%}).)*)(?:{%\h?else\h?%}(?<else>[\s\S]*?))?{%\s*end\h+if\s*%}`](https://regex101.com/r/hJ8gA2/4). You can't get rid of the 2nd group if you want to keep the regex somewhat shorter.